# Error in java installation

Tags: 14.04, java

I am new to ubuntu. I want to  install java on ubuntu. i tried the code

> sudo apt-get install default-jre

but i have got message like this:

> E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource
>   temporarily unavailable) E: Unable to lock the administration
>   directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?

What is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This occurs when you open package manager and install from cmd at same time. Try closing all windows and re execute the command.